# Installing B&R Automation Studio V 4.9.2 C++ redistributable setup not found

Tags: c++, automation, plc, br-automation-studio

When installing B&R Automation Studio V4.9 (when V4.7 is already installed) I get a

> C++ redistributable setup not found

error.

[image: Error message]

In the picture below you see the redistributables of C++ that are already installed.

[image: Packages that are installed]

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by reinstalling B&R Automation Studio V4.9.

I thinks something went wrong with the extraction of the zip file.